# Smooth transition between 2 stylesheets in Angular App

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

So I have 2 different stylesheets in my app (one dark theme and one light theme) which I can toggle to switch the theme. It works fine but I was wondering if it's possible to make a smooth transition animation like this somehow, all be it JS or pure CSS => [image: style transition gif]

my code to toggle the styles looks like this:

```
cssFiles = ["styles-dark.css","styles-light.css"]
toggle() {
    var theme;
    if(localStorage.getItem("theme") == "dark"){
      localStorage.setItem("theme", "light")
      theme = this.cssFiles[1]
    }else{
      localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark")
      theme = this.cssFiles[0]
    }
    
    const head = this.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    let themeLink = this.document.getElementById(
      'mycss'
    ) as HTMLLinkElement;
    if (themeLink) {
      themeLink.href = theme;
    } else {
      const style = this.document.createElement('link');
      style.id = 'mycss';
      style.rel = 'stylesheet';
      style.href = `${theme}`;

      head.appendChild(style);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach I can suggest is to utilize CSS transitions.

1. Create a base stylesheet where you define all styles without the theme-specific rules (probably mostly colors). Set CSS transitions to the properties, that are subject to change. This stylesheet should not be toggled

```
/* base.css */
 body {
   transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 }

 .card {
   transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px
 }

 h3 {
   transition: color 0.5s ease;
 }
```

2. Create stylesheets for the themes:

```
/* styles-light.css */
  body {
    background-color: white;
  }

  .card {
    background-color: gray;
  }

  h3 {
   color: white;
  }

/* styles-dark.css */
  body {
    background-color: black;
  }

  .card {
    background-color: lightgray;
  }

  h3 {
   color: black;
  }
```

3. Toggling between themes should happen with the transition you have defined

Notice that all the easings, transition timings and colors are just for demo purpose. Here is a very simple working example:

```js
// Simplified example for theme stylesheet
const darkTheme = `
  body {
      background-color: black;
    }

    .card {
      background-color: lightgray;
    }

    h3 {
      color: black;
    }
  `;

  document.getElementById('darkThemeToggle').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const styleTag = document.createElement('style');
    styleTag.append(darkTheme)
    document.body.append(styleTag);
  });
```

```css
body {
      transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    }

    .card {
      transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px
    }

    h3 {
      transition: color 0.5s ease;
    }

/* Let's assume the styles below are from the light theme stylesheet */

    body {
      background-color: white;
    }

    .card {
      background-color: gray;
    }

    h3 {
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="card">
    <h3>content</h3>
  </div>

  <button type="button" id="darkThemeToggle">Switch to dark theme</button>
</body>
```